# Deleted files showing in source control in un-related project

Tags: git

I'm new to coding and just installed vite. I don't know if I did it correctly or anything but still learning. Right now I'm having a problem where if I delete a project in my projects folder, the deleted files start showing in my source control for projects where vite is installed. When I enter `git status` into the terminal, this shows up.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/.gitignore
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/README-template.md
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/README.md
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/design/active-states.jpg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/design/desktop-design.jpg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/design/desktop-preview.jpg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/design/mobile-design.jpg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/design/mobile-navigation.jpg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/design/testimonials-slider.jpg        
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/avatar-ali.png
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/avatar-anisha.png
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/avatar-richard.png
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/avatar-shanai.png
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/bg-simplify-section-desktop.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/bg-simplify-section-mobile.svg 
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/bg-tablet-pattern.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/favicon-32x32.png
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/icon-close.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/icon-facebook.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/icon-hamburger.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/icon-instagram.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/icon-pinterest.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/icon-twitter.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/icon-youtube.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/illustration-intro.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/images/logo.svg
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/index.html
        deleted:    ../manage-landing-page-master/style-guide.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
```

So all the files I deleted show up and when I discard the changes in the Source Control panel on VS Code they get restored into my projects folder. Committing these changes only brings up something in VS Code saying `ENTER COMMIT COMMAND` or something like that. Any solutions?

Also side note in the un-tracked part of the terminal message a bunch of other projects from my projects folder show up for some reason. Any solutions in having that not be the case? I don't think they're supposed to show there.

Comment: You are trying to create new repo or you want to use the old one and save the deleted files?

Comment: I don't want the deleted files. Only on the repos where I have vite installed is where these deleted files show in the Source Control tab for VS Code. New to vite so I don't know much on how to navigate it and barely know about the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you initialized your git repo at the level of your projects folder. (I'm going to call it `projects` from here on).

(btw, read until the end before running any commands.)

To confirm this diagnostic, `cd` to `projects`. Then run `ls -a` and look for a `.git` directory. If there's one, then your entire `projects` folder is a git repository.

If that's the case and it's not as intended, you should remove that `.git` directory.

But **before that**, ask yourself if you want to preserve the git history (commits) of that repository.

It's possible to preserve the commit history for each project within `projects`, but it's quite a bit more involved. Ask again if you need that.

Once you have decided to do away with the outer `projects` repository, run `rm -rf .git` from within the `projects` folder.

That line stands for `remove --recursive --force` the `.git` directory. You can try without the `--force` first to learn why that's necessary.

Everything related to a Git repository lives in that `.git` directory, so now it's like it never was a Git repo. You can check that by running `git status`

From now on, you should only run `git init` from within a particular project's directory, never the outer `projects`

Comment: Running `ls - a` didn't show up with much in the VS Code Terminal. Running that in Git Bash did though. This is what came up:

`
$ ls -a
./                                          flex-grid-practice/
../                                         flexbox-business-site-starting/
.git/  
`
There are other projects below the `.git` but there is only one `.git`. Does this mean that my projects folder is being treated as one big repo?

Comment: The thing is the deleted files and un-tracked files aren't showing up in my other projects where vite isn't included.

Comment: @WIDDIT it does look like the projects folder is being treated as one big repo. The `.git/` directory inside `projects` is indicative of that.

I'm not sure why the `git status` isn't corrupted in projects without vite, but a possible answer would be that those projects are git repositories themselves.

git commands, including `status` will look for the nearest `.git/` directory (so git repo) by walking the directory tree upwards.

1/2

Comment: @WIDDIT 2/2

For instance:

with PWD: `~/projects/flex-grid`.

If there's no `.git/` in `flex-grid` but there is in `projects`, the later is the git repo.

If there's `.git/` in both directories, then running `git status` from `flex-grid` treats `flex-grid` as a repo. And running it from `projects` treats `projects` as the repo. It will also detect `flex-grid` as a possible git submodule. But that's a feature of git (submodules) you shouldn't need to learn just yet.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Just last night I was checking to see for `.git/` in my other projects and did see it in the right folders. All my projects with vite don't have `.git/` in their folders. Their `.git/` is indeed in my projects folder. My other projects don't have this problem. 

Every time I created a project with vite I didn't use `git init` to initialize the project. I would do `npm create vite@latest`. What I plan on doing right now is backing up my projects. Deleting the `.git/` in the projects folder and fixing up anything that might be wrong. Hopefully all goes well. Thx

Comment: I believe it all worked out all my projects are seem to work fine. Didn't really need the commit history for the projects where vite was installed. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: No prob! Also, there's no need to initialize your project with `git init`. You can do `git init` on any directory at any point in time, so you can do it right after `npm create`. Or even initialize git in an already mature project. Commit history is hella useful even late into a project, as long as you do atomic commits and use commit messages to explain the rationale behind non-obvious code changes.